# Installing XAMPP error

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I followed [How to install XAMPP 1-8-3 for Linux in Ubuntu Desktop](http://ubuntuportal.com/2013/12/how-to-install-xampp-1-8-3-for-linux-in-ubuntu-desktop.html)

I already installed `lampp` under `/opt`.

I am using the command `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`, I have seen `XAMPP` four of them the first one is starting Apache fail, second and third is already running, and last one is starting `MySQl`

When I try to open `xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4-installer.run` on my desktop, I get this error:

```
there has been an error this installer requires root privileges. please become superuser before executing the installer.
```

Comment: Have you tried executing `sudo ~/Desktop/xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4-installer.run`? This will execute the file as the root user (superuser/su).

Comment: i got error by the message after i downloaded that you gave me the instruction. the error was said " google chrome can not be run as root" please start google chrome as a ormal user. to run as toot, you must specify an alternate - user data- dir for storage of profile information .

Comment: You shouldn't run Google Chrome as root, but the installer you've downloaded.

Comment: in to my computer i checked into my directory files and open to opt there is two folders which are google, and lampp.

Comment: google chrome wont let me to remove the files or move into other folder.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what Google Chrome has to do with this? I understand that you've **successfully** installed XAMPP but Apache fails to start, is this right?

Comment: oh i see, yes thats right Apache fails to start even i tried to update apt-apache2 its already installed.

Comment: You have installed XAMPP and Apache2? Apache2 is already bundled with XAMPP so please remove Apache2 using `sudo apt-get remove apache2` and try to start XAMPP again. XAMPP probably won't start now because port 80 is already in use by the Apache2 you've manually installed.

Comment: i re stall Apache2 and it showing failed

Comment: Index of /

[ICO] Name Last modified Size Description
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: why do i get a the message after i typed localhost and i get this

Comment: Have you removed Apache2?

Comment: yes i removed Apache2 that you gave me the terminal from Louis and i go to localhost. it said opps the file cannot find. then i decided go back to terminal type " sudo apt-get install apache2 " i go check at localhost and it said " Index of / [ICO] Name Last modified Size Description Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80 – " also i got this suspect because when i am trying to open the sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start it still said the Apache fail. it was suppose after Apache install said "it works! for example 2:20 at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmkwB7ZLt8M. any idea?

Answer (score 10):

run  xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4-installer.run as root user using `sudo`

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-4-installer.run
```

Enter your password and hit Enter. You should see the installer.

Answer (score 3):

For gaining the access of super user please ruse this command before running installer

```
sudo -s -H
```

it will make you super user.

From `sudo` man page:

```
-H, --set-home   set HOME variable to target user's home dir
-s, --shell      run shell as the target user; a command may also be specified
```

Then run ./filename.run on the folder XAMPP was downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think xampp changed in ubuntu, ubuntu no longer support xampp in their repo, you will have to download xampp from source and install

```
# wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.3/xampp-linux-1.8.3-4-installer.run
# chmod 755 xampp-linux*
# ./xampp-linux*
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with installation of xampp. just type this command in terminal then install xampp in nautilus simple!

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

right that!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download xampp (use the link given below)
https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

After completed the download go to your **Download** folder in your computer (Ubuntu & Linux)

In your **Download** Folder you can see (xampp-linux-x64-7.3.5-1-installer.run) File.

.run format is you can run it directly pressing enter key (then it will ask for root privilege for execute the file)

Then **Copy** (xampp-linux-x64-7.3.5-1-installer.run) file

Go to **Desktop**

Right Click Your Mouse and click **Open as Root**

Then go to file system and paste it in your **usr** folder (or anywhere you want)

**Double Click** (xampp-linux-x64-7.3.5-1-installer.run) File  (Delete the file after installing)

**Enjoy!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste your `xampp-linux-x64-7.3.6-2-installer.run` to your `/home/<username>/` (your username must be entered as the name you use for log in to Ubuntu without < >).

You can rename your `xampp-linux-x64-7.3.6-2-installer.run` to a simple `installer.run`.

Then open a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+Tand enter the following command:

```
sudo ~/installer.run
```

It will find the installer on your username's parent directory and this executes the installation with no more annoying advertisements.